# Clickable image with Angular 2.x

Tags: html, angular

In `HTML` I want to make a clickable image which then calls a `TypeScript` function using an `Angular` directive. I'm using `Angular` version `2.4.10`.

I tried various snippets but none worked and I always get the warning `Attribute ng-click is not allowed here`:

```
<a ng-click="myTypeScriptFunction()"> <img src="url-to-my-image"/></a>
```

With `onClick()` and an `alert()` dialog it works fine:

```
<a onClick="alert('It worked');"> <img src="url-to-my-image"/></a>
```

How can it be done with `Angular`?

Comment: try angular/cli version

Comment: try to apply ng-click inside img tag it should work

Comment: <img src="image.png" ng-click="myFunction()" />

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383345/angularjs-ng-click-on-img-manipulating-images-kind-of-gallery-like-with-jque

Comment: There's no such thing as 'AngularJS 2'. Don't use this name to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Angular 2/4 for event binding you use

```ts
<a (click)="myTypeScriptFunction()"> ... </a>
```

This is documented here: https://angular.io/docs

Answer (score 4):

change for this code :

```
<a (click)="myTypeScriptFunction()"> <img src="url-to-my-image"/></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `click` event binding

```
<button (click)="yourMethod()"> <img src="url-to-my-image"/></button>
```